# C++ application crash

Tags: c++, linux, gdb

C++ application gets crashed with the core file showing error

```
warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff79e54000
Core was generated by `./server'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted.
#0 0x0000003b67230265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0 0x0000003b67230265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x0000003b67231d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2 0x0000003b6726a9bb in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3 0x0000003b6727247f in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4 0x0000003b672728db in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5 0x00000000004060df in operator delete (p=0x20030190) at ../lib/m_string.cpp:43
#6 0x0000000000403892 in TStr::~TStr (this=0x2102c980, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at ../lib/m_string.cpp:175 –
```

could able to understand about this issue. Here is the link that i have verified https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=959013

shows that the size of vdso file is  not enough. which is in path /proc/self/maps.

please let me know what kind of issue is this and please suggest a fix for this.

Comment: Can you please edit the question to actually include the backtrace?

Comment: Here is the backtrace of the issue.                                     (gdb) bt
#0  0x0000003b67230265 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003b67231d10 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003b6726a9bb in __libc_message () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#3  0x0000003b6727247f in _int_free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000003b672728db in free () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#5  0x00000000004060df in operator delete (p=0x20030190) at ../lib/m_string.cpp:43
#6  0x0000000000403892 in TStr::~TStr (this=0x2102c980, __in_chrg=<value optimized out>) at ../lib/m_string.cpp:175  Regards,Ragu.

Comment: Now you should show what you're doing in the file `m_string.cpp` at line 43 (please show the *whole* function), and please **edit the question** to do it.

Comment: m-string.cpp is an library file in which we have done a memcpy, operator's blah....blah thing..  Mainly we just want to know what kind of error is this                         "warning: no loadable sections found in added symbol-file system-supplied DSO at 0x7fff79e54000
Core was generated by `./server'.
Program terminated with signal 6, Aborted."   Is this happening when the size of the core gets increasing on the file 'vdso' or anything like that.

Comment: You get the crash because you're doing something wrong with memory allocations/deallocations (probably writing to before or after allocated memory). The DSO thing is pretty much irrelevant to what should (IMO) bet the main problem: The crash. And we can't help you fix the crash problem without you showing us what you do.

Comment: To continue my previous comment, you might want to take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn what a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is.

Comment: Perhaps you delete same memory twice on destructor of copy your string? Is there correct deep copy constructor and assigment operator for TStr?

Comment: You can ignore that DSO message.  It is just a warning and is totally ignorable.  Basically the vDSO violates some detail of ELF, but not in any important way.

Answer (score 3):

> what kind of issue is this

Any crash inside `malloc` or `free` is a sure sign of previous heap corruption.

Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) or [AddressSanitizer](https://code.google.com/p/address-sanitizer/) (incorporated into GCC-4.8 as well) to find the root cause.

Ignore `vdso` -- as Tom Tromey said, it has nothing to do with the problem.